# Splitting a variable in two in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to separate the variable potato in 2 because the histogram shows 2 normal distributions in one. So I wanted to make 2 categories of my dataset so that I can treat them separately. Here I want to separate the dataset at a value of 12 approximatively.

If possible, is there a way to do this in dplyr? Also, if I have many Species in my first column and I wanted to do this with only one species with specific traits (I have more than the trait Depth in my original dataset), how could I specify a separation of a trait depending on the species and the trait?

To clarify: Is it possible to split the data with the minimum value between the two peaks in this bi-normal sample? Like, split between mean value of peak one and mean value of peak 2?

This is the dataset:

```
structure(list(Species1 = c("Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", 
"Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes", "Potatoes"), Depth = c(10.3, 
10.47, 12.48, 9.48, 13.07, 12.25, 10.1, 9.38, 9.04, 11.25, 12.52, 
9.96, 10.74, 10.13, 10.88, 12.66, 9.8, 10.7, 9.71, 10.51, 9.67, 
9.12, 11.15, 9.82, 10.21, 10.33, 12.06, 9.58, 9.45, 13.79, 12.61, 
10.97, 10.98, 11.83, 12.52, 12.48, 10.25, 9.67, 9.58, 11, 11.02, 
10.34, 10.09, 12.27, 10.34, 12.5, 10.03, 9.87, 10.38, 10.24, 
10.77, 10.36, 10.63, 9.76, 10.11, 8.69, 12.88, 9.86, 10.7, 10.93, 
10.26, 12.06, 10.43, 11.39, 10.56, 9.68, 11.42, 9.55, 11.29, 
8.69, 12.59, 13.92, 12.31, 10.08, 10.14, 10.21, 12.6, 11.24, 
10.72, 12.3, 12.06, 9.64, 9.77, 10.18, 10.78, 10.18, 11.36, 9.69, 
12.47, 10.73, 9.12, 9.81, 10.69, 12.39, 10.2, 9.86, 12.79, 9.93, 
10.39, 11.63, 10.57, 10.55, 9.09, 11.15, 10.02, 10.94, 10.66, 
9.55, 10.29, 12.04, 10.63, 9.17, 9.78, 10.05, 8.75, 10.99, 13.65, 
9.63, 9.83, 13.61, 11.53, 12.46, 13.55, 11.71, 11.97, 9.62, 10.29, 
11.34, 10.8, 10.35, 9.22, 10.66, 9.52, 13.17, 12.14, 12.48, 12.3, 
10.63, 11.01, 10.3, 9.94, 9.67, 11.73, 9.24, 10.55, 9.96, 10.62, 
9.21, 10.88, 9.5, 9.92, 9.79, 10.13, 11.82, 9.68, 10.39, 8.99, 
8.68, 10.66, 10.01, 13.26, 11.99, 9.89, 10.68, 11.14, 9.63, 10.96, 
10.7, 9.83, 9.79, 9.37, 10.21, 7.58, 10.5, 9.09, 11.79, 11.98, 
9.81, 9.68, 8.86, 8.9, 9.55, 10.26, 9.83, 10.17, 11.01, 9.95, 
9.49, 9.65, 9.64, 10.55, 10.12, 10.78, 9.61, 10.47, 9.81, 10.81, 
9.17, 10.75, 12.35, 10.1, 10.29, 12.02, 9.75, 9.84, 10.04, 10.01, 
9.95, 9.09, 9.26, 10.89, 10.83, 8.84, 12.11, 9.32, 9.37, 9.01, 
10.33, 9.79, 8.51, 9, 10.12, 9.61, 12.59, 9.6, 8.96, 12.03, 9.83, 
11.74, 9.41, 9.56, 9.6, 11.4, 12.91, 9.66, 9.67, 9.31, 11.23, 
11.02, 9.16, 12.08, 12.16, 8.55, 11.9, 8, 13.56, 9.28, 10.24, 
9.6, 12.63, 12.7, 10.17, 10.09, 12.92, 9.69, 10.58, 10.05, 10.36, 
9.18)), .Names = c("Species1", "Depth"), row.names = c(NA, -259L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Expected output is unclear, it appears to me like you want to add a grouping-variable of some sort. Does something like `dat$group <- ifelse(dat$Depth < 12,1,2)` solve your issue?

Comment: Assuming there is 2 normal distribution, they are not well separated if you look at the histogram. Since your question said you have "more than the trait Depth", you might do better to use all other traits to separate out the species. Might add that a group-variable that Heroka suggested is more useful than splitting into 2 data sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I got you right, but simply

```
df1 <- df %>% filter(Depth>12)
df2 <- df %>% filter(Depth<=12)
```

Splits your Dataset in two at 12 with dplyr.

Adding a new formating Variable, same as Heroka said..

```
df3 <- df %>% mutate(DepthClass = ifelse(Depth<12,1,2))
```

Comment: This isn't very practical, as it means that all future operations need to be done on two dataframes.

Comment: It's not, but his question "splitting a variable in two" suggested to me thats what he was looking for.. it's to easy anyway im quite sure he wants something else : )